# Recommended .hgignore file for Python projects?

Tags: python, django, mercurial, hgignore

I'm an experienced iOS developer diving into Python. I'm setting up my first Django project. This is also first time for me to use Mercurial for version control (before I heavily used SVN, then GIT).

I'm trying to create a nice **`.hgignore`** file. So far I have:

```
syntax: glob
bin/**
include/**
lib/**
pip-selfcheck.json
.Python
```

What other files should I put there? I'm using `virtualenv` and `pip` to create my development environment.
Thanks for help!

Comment: `*.pyc` is a good one to include. You could also look at the [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) suggestions and take some from there.

Comment: Have you looked at any on e.g. GitHub? Django itself has one, for example.

Comment: Have some templates from git https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore

Comment: @giaosudau, this link is very helpful, I'll look into that! thanks

Comment: @Brobin I used to ignore `*.pyc`, but reading a .gitignore the other day had me realise I could just ignore `__pycache__`, which is faster as the versioning tool will not enter the directory at all. Ofc, that's for python 3 only.

Comment: Setuptools: exclude `build/`, `dist/`, and `*.egg_info/`.  Sphinx: exclude `docs/_build/`.  Virtualenv: exclude your venv directory.  If you have more than one, give them a common naming scheme like `venv-*` so you can exclude them all at once.  Ctags: exclude the `tags` file (and set up commit/update hooks to regenerate the file automatically).  C extensions: exclude `*.so`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just searched and it appears there is an example in the Django repo at [Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/.hgignore) ([raw text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/django/django/master/.hgignore)) - the current version is:

```
syntax:glob

*.egg-info
*.pot
*.py[co]
__pycache__
MANIFEST
dist/
docs/_build/
docs/locale/
node_modules/
tests/coverage_html/
tests/.coverage
build/
tests/report/
```

Note that some of that seems specific to their layout, but I'm still starting from this rather than from one of my own .gitignore files (I use git for my projects, but today I'm creating an example for another team that uses hg).